# MySQL join, order not correct

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
tickets

ticket_id, int(11), NO, PRI, , auto_increment
order_num, varchar(45), NO, , , 
user_id, int(11), YES, , , 
event_id, int(11), YES, , , 
number_of_tickets, varchar(4), YES, , , 
order_placed, timestamp, NO, , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
payment_recd, enum('Yes','No'), YES, , No, 
payment_time, timestamp, YES, , , 

events

event_id, int(11), NO, PRI, , auto_increment
venue_id, int(11), YES, , , 
event_date, date, YES, , , 
event_time, time, YES, , , 
event_price, decimal(4,2), YES, , , 
event_capacity, int(11), YES, , , 
dateadded, timestamp, NO, , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

I need to list tickets bought by a user and order by the event date but the following I'm trying is not doing the sort by correctly

```
select tickets.order_num as ordnum, tickets.event_id as tickid, tickets.number_of_tickets as numtix 
   from tickets, events
where  ((tickets.user_id = '1') and (tickets.payment_recd = 'Yes'))
  group by tickets.order_num 
order by events.event_date asc
```

Any ideas?

Comment: and what is incorrent? how order looks?

Comment: I don't see you use the table `events` in your query ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not joining the tables, so it will list all rows from both tables, try:

```
select tickets.order_num as ordnum, tickets.event_id as tickid, tickets.number_of_tickets as numtix 
from tickets
inner join events on tickets.event_id = events.event_id
where ((tickets.user_id = '1') && (tickets.payment_recd = 'Yes'))
group by tickets.order_num order by events.event_date asc
```

Answer (score 1):

First i recommend to you use `JOIN` because your approach is too slow and `JOIN` is fastest, much more safer and actually the most efficient solution that you are able to use and database-correct-written.

```
SELECT t.order_num, t.event_id, t.number_of_tickets 
FROM tickets t
INNER JOIN events e ON (t.event_id = e.event_id)
WHERE ((t.user_id = '1') && (t.payment_recd = 'Yes'))
GROUP BY t.order_num
ORDER BY e.event_date ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
select tickets.order_num as ordnum, tickets.event_id as tickid, tickets.number_of_tickets as numtix 
   from events
  inner join tickets on events.id = ticket.event_id
where  ((tickets.user_id = '1') and (tickets.payment_recd = 'Yes'))
  group by tickets.order_num 
order by events.event_date asc
```

You don't show the relation between `events` and `tickets` tables, getting a cartesian product.

Answer (score 0):

You need a 'AND tickets.event_id = events.event_id' in your where clause.

You haven't specified how to join the two tables, so at the moment you're doing a full join.

Answer (score 0):

try to use it

```
 select tickets.order_num as ordnum, tickets.event_id as tickid,
 tickets.number_of_tickets as numtix from tickets inner join events on
    tickets.event_id=events.event_id where
 ((tickets.user_id = 1) && (tickets.payment_recd = 'Yes'))
 group by tickets.order_num order by events.event_date asc
```

and please consider that tickets.user_id is an integer, you cant behave it as a string with ''...
it must be like try to use it tickets.user_id = 1